# Implement Excel 2013 macro which hides empty columns

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to implement a macro in Microsoft Excel 2013 which hides columns with no entries.

In the following example, the columns B, D, G and I should be hidden after the macro has been executed. Another macro should make all columns visible again.

[image: Example Excel Sheet]

Only columns which have entries in the first row and only rows which haven entries in the first column shall be considered.

Comment: `Because I am not familiar with macro programming at all...` - sory, we are not freelance site. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. _Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results_. See also [help]. So, what have you tried so far? If nothing, start from using [Macro Recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the Macro recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a crash course in VBA today and found the following solution for my problem:

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To N
        Set rnData = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1000, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If wf.CountA(rnData) < 2 Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Because I am not a programming guy I would really appreciate any comments regarding that solution. Are there some mistakes in this implementation or is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?

Comment: (Dramatically) increased performance of VBA code since - in our case - the number of rows can be limited to 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KolumHider()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To N
        If wf.CountA(Cells(1, i).EntireColumn) < 2 Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this works great. Is it possible to extend it in a way that it only considers rows which are not filtered out by some criteria? F. e., rows containing data3 and data4 have been filtered out. This means that also column C and F have to be hidden.